# Prove that $X_p$ is a vector at $p$

Tags: manifolds, lie-groups, group-actions

In the William Boothby book (An introduction to differentiable manifolds and Riemannian geometry) there is a definition of *infinitesimal generators* that using definition below, it can be proved that $X_p$ is a vector at $p$.

> **Definition:** We define that *Tangent Space* $T_p(M)$ to $M$ at $P$ to be set of all mappings $X_P:C^\infty(p)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ satisfying for all $\alpha, \beta \in \mathbb{R}$ and $f,g \in C^\infty(p)$ the two conditions
>
> (i) $X_p(\alpha f+ \beta g)=\alpha (X_p f)+\beta(X_p g)$  (linearity)
>
> (ii) $X_p(fg)=(X_p f)g(p)+f(p)(X_p g)$  (Leibniz rule)
>
> with the vector space operations in $T_p(M)$ defined by $$(X_p+Y_p)f=X_pf+Y_pf,$$ $$(\alpha X_p)f=\alpha(X_pf).$$A *tangent vector* to $M$ at $p$ is any $X_p \in T_p(M)$.

Now, what is the *infinitesimal generator*?

> Suppose that $\theta:\mathbb{R} \times M \rightarrow M$ is any $C^\infty$-action. Then it defines on $M$ a $C^\infty$-vector field $X$, which we shall call the *infinitesimal generator* of $\theta$, according to the following prescription: For each $p \in M$ we define $X_p:C^\infty(p) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ by $$X_pf=\lim_{\Delta t\to 0} \frac{1}{\Delta t} [f(\theta_{\Delta t} (p))-f(p)].$$

Now, the book says that using the first definition, it is obvious that $X_p$ is a vector. Actually, the first condition is easy to check and I have done that! But, When I try to prove that it satisfies the second one, IT SUCKS!!!

So, any help is definitely appreciated!

Comment: Do you mean the Leibniz rule? Obviously it satisfies this condition, since $X_p$ is the derivative operator acted on $f$, did you see in calculus 1 the proof that $(fg)'=f'g+fg'$? if yes, then it's the same proof.

Comment: But how about the $\theta_{\Delta t}$? I mean the variables make some problems that I cannot understand.., @MathematicalPhysicist

Comment: @Lysn then what is exactly the definition of $C^{\infty}$-action in your book? I assume it's something like: $\theta_{\Delta t}(p) = p+\Delta t v$, where $v$ is some unit vector in $M$. Otherwise I don't see how you can prove this claim.

Comment: We call $\theta: \mathbb{R} \times M \rightarrow M$ a $C^\infty$ action of the group $mathbb{R}$ on $M$, which $\mathbb{R}$ is the additive lie group of real numbers and $M$ is a smooth manifold and $\theta_{\Delta t} (p)= \theta (\Delta t , p)$ which is any action that satisfies in $\theta_0 (p)=p$ $\forall p \in M$ and $\theta_{s+t}(p)=\theta_s o \theta_t (p) =\theta_{t+s} (p)$. Here, we didn't define any special action and the claim is supposed to work for all smooth actions.